# Magento installer script not working 1.9

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.9

I have created a custom module using Magento's developer guide but the installer script is not working. I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKMnT.png)

My config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mdg_Giftregistry>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mdg_Giftregistry>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mdg_giftregistry>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mdg_Giftregistry</module>
                    <frontName>giftregistry</frontName>
                </args>
            </mdg_giftregistry>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mdg_giftregistry>
                <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mdg_giftregistry_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mdg_giftregistry>
            <mdg_giftregistry_mysql4>
                <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <entity>
                        <table>mdg_giftregistry_entity</table>
                    </entity>
                    <item>
                        <table>mdg_giftregistry_item</table>
                    </item>
                    <type>
                        <table>mdg_giftregistry_type</table>
                    </type>
                </entities>
            </mdg_giftregistry_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <mdg_giftregistry_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mdg_Giftregistry</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mdg_giftregistry_setup>
            <mdg_giftregistry_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mdg_giftregistry_write>
            <mdg_giftregistry_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mdg_giftregistry_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <mdg_giftregistry>
                <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Block</class>
            </mdg_giftregistry>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mdg_giftregistry>
                <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Helper</class>
            </mdg_giftregistry>
        </helpers>

    </global>
</config>
```

this is installer script

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
// Create the mdg_giftregistry/registry table
$tableName = $installer->getTable('mdg_giftregistry/entity');
// Check if the table already exists
if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
$table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable($tableName)->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
null,
array(
'identity' => true,
'unsigned' => true,
'nullable' => false,
'primary' => true,
),
'Entity Id'
)
->addColumn('customer_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
null,
array(
'unsigned' => true,
'nullable' => false,
'default' => '0',
),
'Customer Id'
)
->addColumn('type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
null,
array(
'unsigned' => true,
'nullable' => false,
'default' => '0',
),
'Type Id')
->addColumn('website_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
null,
array(
'unsigned' => true,
'nullable' => false,
'default' => '0',
),
'Website Id'
)
->addColumn('event_name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255,
array(),
'Event Name'
)
->addColumn('event_date', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE,
null,
array(),
'Event Date'
)->addColumn('event_country', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
3,
array(),
'Event Country'
)
->addColumn('event_location', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
255,array(),
'Event Location'
)
->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
null,
array(
'nullable' => false,
),
'Created At')
->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('mdg_giftregistry/entity',
array('customer_id')),
array('customer_id'))
->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('mdg_giftregistry/entity',
array('website_id')),
array('website_id'))
->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('mdg_giftregistry/entity',
array('type_id')),
array('type_id'))
->addForeignKey(
$installer->getFkName(
'mdg_giftregistry/entity',
'customer_id',
'customer/entity','entity_id'
),
'customer_id', $installer->getTable('customer/entity'),
'entity_id',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
->addForeignKey(
$installer->getFkName(
'mdg_giftregistry/entity',
'website_id',
'core/website',
'website_id'
),
'website_id', $installer->getTable('core/website'),
'website_id',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
->addForeignKey(
$installer->getFkName('mdg_giftregistry/entity',
'type_id',
'mdg_giftregistry/type',
'type_id'
),
'type_id', $installer->getTable('mdg_giftregistry/type'),
'type_id',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE);
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
}
$installer->endSetup();
```

My directory structure is

Comment: You need to read [ask]. If you've written the installer script then please show us the code. If the custom module has failed because of its code then please show us that.

Comment: This is not suitable on Stack Overflow - possibly on http://magento.stackexchange.com but make sure to check their "How to ask"  first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Class 'Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Resource_Setup' not found

This is because you're referencing a custom setup class in your config.xml:

```
<setup>
    <module>Mdg_Giftregistry</module>
    <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
</setup>
```

I assume that you haven't created the class yet, so you have two options:

1. Create the class `Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Resource_Setup` which would extend `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`:

   ```
   # File: app/code/local/Mdg/Giftregistry/Model/Resource/Setup.php
   class Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
   {

   }
   ```
2. Change your config.xml entry so it uses the core class:

   ```
   <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
   ```

You are likely to still have more problems with your installers, but without sharing your code it's hard to know/predict.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I have already created a setup class. but after changing to core class i got a entry in Core_Resource table but still installer script not work. I add installer script in que also.

Comment: To properly debug your installer script you'll need to provide the filename of the installer, your full config.xml file, the version number of your setup resource in `core_resource`, and the directory structure of your module.

Comment: Hi I am update my full config.xml, installer script, directory structure image and i have entry in core resource table with 0.1.0 please check it

Comment: What's the installer script file name and directory structure?

Comment: Thanks  sql->mdg_giftregistry_ setup->install-0.1.0.php n directory structure image is also added

Comment: Your question is answered. You must be facing a different problem now, suggest you ask a new question and provide an example of why it's not working

Comment: can not understand i am new in magento n this is my first module can you please explain it?